# How to create Android AVD from terminal which has specific config.ini and multi-core CPU

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

1. How can I apply config.ini file to AVD during creation from terminal?
2. How can I create AVD from terminal which has multi-core CPU set to 4? Every AVD I create from terminal has always only 1 core.